# How to accurately multiply a COleCurrency by a double?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, mfc

I have a `COleCurrency` object that represents a unit price. And I have a `double` value that represents a quantity. And I need to calculate the total dollar amount to the nearest penny.

Looks like `COleCurrency` has built in multiplication operators, but only for multiplication with a `long` value.

I can multiply `COleCurrency.m_cur.int64` by the `double`, but that converts the `double` to `__int64` so it wouldn't be accurate.

What is the best way to accurately multiply a `COleCurrency` by a `double`?

Comment: `(__int64)dbl` will truncate the double and might not give the result you expect ie if `dbl` is `1.999999999....` this will be truncated to `1` before doing the multiplication.  You probably want to use `std::llround(dbl)` see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/round

Comment: @RichardCritten: Right, but the __int64 part is in 100ths of a penny. So it might not be an issue. But maybe I should round for good measure.

Comment: You cannot use binary floating point values and expect accuracy in the decimal numeral system. Binary floating point values cannot even represent most fractional decimals, such as `0.1`. You need to explain what *"accurately"* means in your context.

Comment: @IInspectable: That was kind of the point of posting this question. The pieces don't seem to fit together. And yet that's what I have to work with. If it wasn't obvious from my use of `COleCurrency`, I'm calculating a dollar amount. So *accurately* would refer to the nearest penny.

Comment: When you say the double represents a "quantity", does that mean it is ALWAYS a whole number (but still may or may not fit in a 64 bit int, e.g. 1E+100).  A different set of questions whose answers may be helpful, what is the expected range of the double, and similarly what is the expected accuracy (whole integer, hundredths, or 1E-100?)

Comment: @franji1: I'm given a double for the quantity exactly because it is not always (and in fact is almost always not) a whole number.

Comment: *"I can multiply `COleCurrency.m_cur.int64` by the `double`, but that converts the `double` to `__int64` so it wouldn't be accurate."* - That's incorrect. When an expression multiplies an integer value and a floating point value, the integer value is implicitly converted to the appropriate floating point type, not the other way around.

Comment: @IInspectable: I think you're mistaken here. The warning I'm given is *"conversion from 'double' to '__int64', possible loss of data"*. Seems that the compiler decided the target type is `__int64`.

Comment: The warning is the result of *assigning* to an `__int64`. You can change `__int64 x = ...` to `double x = ...` to verify this.

Comment: @IInspectable: Ok, you may be right about that. I've already changed the code to the suggestion in your answer, and no longer have the original code. But converting both to `double` is what your suggestion does, and it seems accurate. I had concerns about `double` having enough precision for currency. But since we're dealing in 1/100ths of a penny, I think it's good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finite binary floating point values form a proper subset of finite decimal values. While any given floating point value has an exact, finite representation in decimal, the opposite isn't true. In other words, not every decimal can be represented using a finite binary floating point value. A simple example is `0.1` that produces an **infinite** sequence of binary digits when converted to a binary floating point value.

The important point here is that if you are dealing with fractional values, using binary floating point values to represent them will in general introduce inaccuracies (with *very* few exceptions, such as `0.5`). The only way to perform accurate multiplications with an integer value is to use an integer as the multiplicand.

Since you have opted to use a floating point value the only thing you can do is limit the inaccuracies. The proposed solution:

```cpp
__int64 x = currency.m_cur.int64 * (__int64)dbl;
```

suffers from the same *"possible loss of data"* issue the compiler warned about. Since you're now using an explicit cast, this silences the compiler. The effect is still the same: The floating point value gets truncated.

A better approach would be to convert the 64-bit integer value to a `double` first. This produces an *exact* floating point representation of the integer value, provided that it is within range (roughly +/- 1e15). You can then multiply with another floating point value (which is subject to rounding errors), and finally round the result using, e.g., [`std::llround`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/round):

```cpp
__int64 x = std::llround(static_cast<double>(currency.m_cur.int64) * dbl);
```